# tinymce save_callback called 4 times each save

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE and it's jQuery plugin.

I added a function to be called each time the save button is clicked, like this:

```
$('#my:textarea').tinymce({ 
    save_callback: function() { console.log('saving things!'); }
});
```

It's called 4 times each time the user clicks the save button; should I be putting my callback somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:save_callback), `save_callback` is considered deprecated. It suggests you to use the new Event API.

Give this a try:

```
$('#my:textarea').tinymce({
   setup : function(ed){
      ed.onSaveContent.add(function(ed, o) {
          // Output the element name
          console.debug(o.element.nodeName);
      });
   }
});
```

Example grabbed from here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onSaveContent

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware the tinyMCE.init stuff also applied to the jquery plugin.  It's only being called twice now,  is there a way to make it be called once when the save button is clicked?

Comment: Hmm... I have actually never used TinyMCE with jQuery. :) I set up a test on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xgPzS/2/ It seems that it's called twice because when you press the save button, it automatically submits the underlying form, which triggers save again. I can't even stop the submit from jQuery. However if you set `submit_patch:false` it only calls save once (although I think it should prevent submit, which it does not do). Have a look at `submit_patch` and `add_form_submit_trigger` on the docs page, see if it makes more sense to you: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration